# SQL Database trigger ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to enter customer name, start date and ship name into the audit table if the booking evaluation number is 2. I am getting an invalid identifier error when the name I am using is in the booking table. For now, I am just trying to get the customer name in the audit table so therefore got null in the other columns.

This is the code I have I cant see where I am going wrong:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EVALUATION
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.BOOKING_EVALUATION = 2)
DECLARE

custname  VARCHAR(20);
sdate    DATE;
shname   VARCHAR(50);

BEGIN

SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME INTO custname FROM customer WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME = NEW.CUSTOMER_NAME;


IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO EVALUATIONAUDIT (VOYAGES_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,START_DATE,SHIP_NAME,BOOKING_EVALUATION)
VALUES(:NEW.VOYAGES_ID,custname,NULL,NULL,:NEW.BOOKING_EVALUATION);
END IF;


IF UPDATING THEN
INSERT INTO EVALUATIONAUDIT (VOYAGES_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,START_DATE,SHIP_NAME,BOOKING_EVALUATION)
VALUES(:OLD.VOYAGES_ID,custname,NULL,NULL,:OLD.BOOKING_EVALUATION);
END IF;


IF DELETING THEN
INSERT INTO EVALUATIONAUDIT (VOYAGES_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,START_DATE,SHIP_NAME,BOOKING_EVALUATION)
VALUES(:OLD.VOYAGES_ID,custname,NULL,NULL,:OLD.BOOKING_EVALUATION);
END IF;
END;
/
```

This is the error I am getting:

> 9/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   9/67     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."CUSTOMER_NAME": invalid identifier

Comment: Is there a column `CUSTOMER_NAME` in the table `BOOKING`?

Comment: No it is in customer table i don't have customer name in booking table.

Comment: Then you cannot use `NEW.CUSTOMER_NAME` in a trigger on `BOOKING`. (Even if you put the missing `:` before it.)

Comment: I have customer id in the booking table but i need to add the customer name from the customer table to the audit table when the booking evaluation is 2.

Comment: Then change the query getting the customer name to use the ID instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a field from the `NEW` pseudorecord, and since the table the trigger is against only has the ID, you need to use that for the look-up:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME
INTO custname
FROM customer
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Notice the `:` prefix for `NEW`, as well as the column/field name change.

This won't quite work for the `IF DELETING` branch though, as the `NEW` pseudorecord will be empty in that case - only `OLD` is populated. So you need additional logic to get the customer name based on `OLD` or `NEW` depending on the triggering event, and based on you using `OLD` in the `UPDATING` branch you might want the old customer ID there too.

The `WHEN (NEW.BOOKING_EVALUATION = 2)` check won't work on delete either, for the same reason.

So you could maybe do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EVALUATION
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE

  custname  VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN

  IF INSERTING AND :NEW.BOOKING_EVALUATION = 2 THEN
    SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME
    INTO custname
    FROM customer
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;

    INSERT INTO EVALUATIONAUDIT (VOYAGES_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,START_DATE,SHIP_NAME,BOOKING_EVALUATION)
    VALUES(:NEW.VOYAGES_ID,custname,NULL,NULL,:NEW.BOOKING_EVALUATION);
  END IF;

  IF (UPDATING OR DELETING) AND :OLD.BOOKING_EVALUATION = 2 THEN
    SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME
    INTO custname
    FROM customer
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :OLD.CUSTOMER_ID;

    INSERT INTO EVALUATIONAUDIT (VOYAGES_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,START_DATE,SHIP_NAME,BOOKING_EVALUATION)
    VALUES(:OLD.VOYAGES_ID,custname,NULL,NULL,:OLD.BOOKING_EVALUATION);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

depending on whether you want to record an update if the old, new or either `BOOKING_EVALUATION` is 2. This version only looks at `OLD`in the `UPDATING OR DELETING` as those are the other values you're using for the insert, but could easily check either, or you could split the `UPDATING` and `DELETING` out again. Or you could change the first check to:

```
...
BEGIN

  IF (INSERTING OR UPDATING) AND :NEW.BOOKING_EVALUATION = 2 THEN
...
```

It depends what scenarios you want to capture and what values you want to record for them.

---

If you get a compilation error then either run `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual failures. If you get ORA-04098 then the trigger that error refers to is invalid - it either was when it was compiled or (less likely here I think) the table structure has changed since it last successfully compiled.

You may have created multiple triggers. Look at the output of

```
select trigger_name, status from user_triggers where table_name = 'BOOKING';
```

to see how many triggers there are against this table (though it could be elsewhere) and what they are called - if there is more than one then see if you have an earlier attempt with a different name that you need to drop.

And look at

```
select object_name, status from user_objects where object_type = 'TRIGGER';
```

to see all the triggers you have defined and look for any which are invalid. You can then go back to the `user_triggers` view to see which tables they are against if it isn't obvious from their names.

Whatever is invalid though, the reason will be visible in `user_errors`.

Comment: when trying to update the booking table i get an error saying:  SQL> UPDATE BOOKING
  2  SET BOOKING_EVALUATION = 2
  3  WHERE BOOKING_ID = 1421;
UPDATE BOOKING
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'OPS$1319260.EVALUATION_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed
re-validation  The trigger was created with no errors

Comment: @Moraqib - is that this trigger (which is called just `EVALUATION` in the question and my answer); or have you created two trigger on this table with different names? Look in `user_triggers` to check that actually exists for `table_name='BOOKING` and if you have multiple drop any you don't actually need. Then if what is left is invalid, query `user_errors` to see why.

Comment: It is the trigger in the answer, the trigger creates which no errors but when trying to update the booking table thats the error i get.

Comment: But the name in the message is different? What can you see in `user_errors`?

Comment: the trigger in the answer that the one i used the trigger creates with no problems its just when i'm updating an error occurs. This is the output of select * from user_errors:

Comment: the trigger in the answer that the one i used the trigger creates with no problems its just when i'm updating an error occurs. The user_errors says bad bind variable NEW.SHIP_NAME, Bad bind variable NEW.START_DATE, bad bind variable NEW.CUSTOMER_NAME.

Comment: Neither trigger uses `:NEW.SHIP_NAME` etc. Either you've modified the trigger int he answer to try to use `:NEW.SHIP_NAME` and the others when those columns don't exist in `BOOKING` - you maybe want to look those up like the customer name? - or you have a second trigger that is doing that.  I've added some notes on tracking down the errors to my answer.

Comment: There was an extra trigger created i have dropped the trigger and now i can update the booking table but when updating the booking evaluation to 2 the evaluation audit table shows no row selected.

Comment: OK, good. That was something I queried in my answer, in the paragraph under my complete trigger. So you do want an audit record on update if the new value is 2; what about if an updates it from 2 to something else? The audit record is only getting the old value (in mine, and your original).

Comment: @Moraqib - I've added an option you can try, but it depends what you really want to happen. Helping you figure out what the desired behaviour is, and then changing the trigger to match that, is outside the scope of this question though - the error you were getting is resolved. Try to clearly set out, for yourself, what you want to happen and then try to modify the trigger to do that. If you then get stuck then ask a new question - but your requirement needs to be clear first. Good luck,

Comment: Yes i will want an audit record if the booking evaluation is 2 and not if it updates from 2 to something else just if it is updated from for example 3 to 2 i would want audit id and customer name in the audit table. I did update the booking table but there was no record in the evaluationaudit table.